# RESTFUL App in symfony 3

Tags: angularjs, rest, api, symfony, jobs

I am still quite confused about REST API, Angular and so on.

I would like to build simple web app which allows users to book events and I would like to do it in `Symfony 3 + Angular`. 
In future, I could make it work on mobile phones as well.

The reason I want to do it is to learn symphony 3, REST API and Angular better and to increase chance I will get hired.

**I have few questions:**

1) Apart of the fact I am going to learn Angular what is the real benefit of using Angular rather than twig templates and HTML for the front end ?

2) As far I have seen people usually suggesting light weight frameworks to build REST API. Why would not they suggest symphony ?

3) What would you suggest to build to show you have got good skill set to get hired ?

Comment: why don't you try laravel? better learning curve than symfony

Comment: as I have built app in symphony 2 already so I would like to improve the knowledge

Answer (score 0):

1) Angular a complete framework. In your case, you would use angular as front end. This would be two options.

- First one is completely using Angular, Symfony serves the RESTful API. Then twig is not involved anymore.
- The other is used Angular within twig, acting like a server side rendering Angular. This way is not very common right now, rather less examples could be found.

In any case, Angular could provide single-page application, which could give your users better user experience, faster load speed, move the html view part completely to browser(make server less tasks regarding rendering the view). You could also achieve this by using twig+javascript, but it would be a bit more complex depends on your skills.

But in my opinion, the best benefits would be separate the frontend and backend from architecture perspective.

2) Symfony is a very complete PHP framework. Building a REST API is only an example of using Symfony. And in this way, some features from Symfony could not be used. I would say some lightweight framework would deliver the same result as using Symfony. It would also be easier using some lightweight framework(less code, less configuration, etc.). However, the performance of Symfony and large community might also need to take into consideration when you choose the right framework.

3) Always a good protfolio by showing your experience and skills.

Comment: Thanks for answer. 2) I am probably not going to use whole potential of Symfony but still I think its nice framework to work with and then to build even the REST API. 3) I was more asking about something concrete what would impress. In my opinion the app I mentioned should be good enough.